# How do you include mpl_toolkits in a Python PEX file

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'd like to create a [PEX](https://pex.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) file from a script that I've written that imports `mpl_toolkits.basemap`. I've tried a number of things, including downloading the [basemap](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/download.html) .tar.gz, untarring it, and placing it in my working directory and trying to use it as a source.

```
pex -r numpy -r matplotlib -s basemap-1.0.7 -s my_project -e my_project.my_project:main -o project.pex
```

Running the resulting PEX file gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/connor/venv/scan_directory.pex/.bootstrap/_pex/pex.py", line 216, in execute
    working_set = self._env.activate()
  File "/Users/connor/venv/scan_directory.pex/.bootstrap/_pex/environment.py", line 123, in activate
    self._working_set = self._activate()
  File "/Users/connor/venv/scan_directory.pex/.bootstrap/_pex/environment.py", line 143, in _activate
    resolved = working_set.resolve(all_reqs, env=self)
  File "/Users/connor/venv/scan_directory.pex/.bootstrap/pkg_resources.py", line 639, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
DistributionNotFound: mpl-toolkits.basemap
```

My script is sitting in a package directory with a `setup.py` file and a separate directory containing my source code and an empty `__init__.py` file, and I think that's mostly alright. This is my `setup.py` script,

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup( name='my_project',
       version='0.1',
       install_requires=[ 'numpy',\
                          'matplotlib',\
                          'mpl_toolkits.basemap'],
       packages=find_packages() )
```

Should I have added statements to `__init__.py`?